# A6200 WIFI USB adapter for Ubuntu12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I recently bought a new wireless card for a computer I built but forgot to make sure there was any kind of Linux support. I was wondering if anyone could help me set up the drivers for the system?

Comment: Are you talking about [this](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-adapters/a6200.aspx) device?

Comment: Yes, i am wondering if there are any drivers for it for Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your device from the terminal: lsusb